# What is the best way to optimize Vuex or other methods to improve the initial loading speed of the backup history interface?

Tags: vue.js, performance, web, optimization, vuex

I do web front-end development in a backup company, now to solve a front-end performance problems, such as tens of thousands of history in the backup job history opened very stuck, mentor told me that it is not a rendering performance problems, it is the vuex to deal with the data bidirectional binding and other aspects of the problem is that a large amount of data memory consumption is high, vuex will be the depth of traversal of the entire object to set the vuex will traverse the entire object in depth to set getter and setter, resulting in a large amount of data will have obvious performance problems. Experimental scenarios are not very good test verification, such as direct calls to the interface, create a large number of storage pools, such as the creation of 10,000 or more storage pools in order to simulate this environment.

Now I want to ask what is the best way to optimize Vuex or other methods to optimize the first screen loading speed of the backup history interface?

Hopefully examples will be given to help me understand.

Comment: The question is too broad. It's unknown what's your case exactly, you didn't even mention vue version. Usually performance problems are caused by the places where data is used, e.g. ui updates, not data itself

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.